# Pointers and pointers to reference

Tags: c++, pointers

Having a structure

```
struct Person{
    Person( int i):id(i){};
    Person * next;
    int id;
};

class Test{
public:
    void addList( Person *&f , Person *&l , int i){

        Person *tmp = new Person(i);
        if( f == nullptr ){

            f = tmp;
            l = tmp;
            return;
        }

        first -> next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
    void addArr( int *arr , int i ){
        arr[index++] = i;
    }
    void print( ){
        for( int i = 0; i < index; i ++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    Person *first = nullptr;
    Person *last = nullptr;
    int index = 0;
    int *arr = new int[10];
};
```

function `addList` add node into linked list and `addArr` adds element into `arr`.
My question is about pointer and reference pointer.

in

```
void addList( Person *&f , Person *&l , int i){

    Person *tmp = new Person(i);
    if( f == nullptr ){

        f = tmp;
        l = tmp;
        return;
    }

    first -> next = tmp;
    last = tmp;
}
```

I need to pass pointer as reference. Otherwise , the local copy of pointer would be changed not outer. I assume  compilator creates something like

```
Person *temporary = new Person(*f);
```

But would I not have to pass array by reference?
I am quite confused by this fact.

Answer (score 1):

> But would i do not have to pass array by reference?

Not in this case, by passing your `Person` pointer by reference in the `addList` function, you are able to alter the pointer itself. That is like saying, *"**Pointer**, use a different address"*. This is possible, as it was passed by reference.

Whereas in your `addArr` function, you are not altering the pointer to the array itself. Rather, you are altering the data that is pointed to. *"**Pointed to data**, use a different value"*. This data `arr` is pointing to is the same data outside the scope of the function.

So, no, you don't have to pass the array by reference.

Comment: so if the first / last already pointed to first element , i could just pass pointer without reference?

Comment: Yes, you could. You only need to pass the pointer by reference (or as a pointer to a pointer), if you wish to alter the pointer itself.